# Create Vector Ranges From Variables

Tags: matlab

I have two vectors that hold the "start" and "end" locations (as logicals) that I wish to combine as to create a third vector, `Final`:

```
Starts = [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0];
Ends =   [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0];
```

With the Final Vector looking like this:

```
Final =  [0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0];
```

Currently, I can accomplish this using a `for` loop as follows:

```
Start_Locations = find(Starts);
End_Locations = find(Ends);
Final = zeros(20,1);

for x=1:length(Start_Locations)

    Final(Start_Locations(x):End_Locations(x),1) = 1;

end
```

I was wondering if there's a way to accomplish the same exact thing without a `for` loop.  For example, I could accomplish what I outlined above with the following "hard-coded" statement:

```
Final([4:8,11:19],1) = 1;
```

Specifically, is there a way to combine the `Start_Locations` and `End_Locations` vectors in a way such that I could have a single statement like:

```
Final(Combined_Start_and_End_Locations,1) = 1;
```

to accomplish what I did with the `for` loop above?  I'm trying to learn to avoid `for` loops as much as I can and would really appreciate any solution that creates the `Final` vector as described above without resorting to a loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problems like this can often be solved using either [`diff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) or [`cumsum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html). They are essentially discrete derivative and integration functions.

For your problem I believe that

```
Final = cumsum([Starts 0]-[0 Ends]);
Final = Final(1:end-1);
```

achieves the desired result.

Comment: In that case this solution returns `[0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]` which seems correct to me.

Comment: Yeah you are right, I was thinking something else I guess! +1

Comment: @Trogdor thanks so much! Strangely, this is the first time I've come across `cumsum` (still new to Matlab).  Do you know of any good online guides regarding the use of `cumsum` or just "creative" manipulation of vectors in general?

Comment: I don't know of any resources, @Divakar may have some tips. bsxfun is another very powerful tool for vectorizing for loops.

Comment: @Alarik `cumsum`, `diff`, `bsxfun`, `all`, `any`, `accumarray` that I could recall off the top of my head as a general case for vectorizing/avoiding loops thing!

Comment: This problem came up a couple of times, but thats the best solution I have seen so far!